# Mongodb Windows Install Fail

Tags: windows, mongodb, installation

I am trying to install mongodb on my local computer.  I have windows 7 and 64 bit.  I am following these instructions which are given on mongo's website:

```
64-bit binaries:

Download and extract the 64-bit .zip.

Unzip the downloaded binary package to the location of your choice. You may want to 
rename mongo-xxxxxxx to just "mongo" for convenience.

Create a data directory:

By default MongoDB will store data in \data\db, but it won't 
automatically create that folder, so we do so here:

    C:\> mkdir \data
    C:\> mkdir \data\db

Or you can do this from the Windows Explorer, of course.

If you prefer to place datafiles elsewhere, use the --dbpath command line parameter 
when starting mongod.exe.  Run and connect to the server

The important binaries for a first run are:

    mongod.exe - the database server. Try mongod --help to see startup options.
    mongo.exe - the administrative shell

To run the database, click mongod.exe in Explorer, or run it from a CMD window.

    C:\> cd \mongodb\bin
    C:\mongodb\bin> mongod

Note: It is also possible to run the server as a Windows Service. But we can do that 
later.
```

When i follow these steps i get the following error:

```
'C:\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch 
file.
```

I am not sure what is going wrong i have followed the direction exactly.  I extracted the zip file on my c drive as mongodb.  I then created the folder data on my c drive and the folder db inside the data folder.  I start the windows cmd line and do as they suggest and i get the above error.  Can anyone help please.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't type the `C:\>`, that's the command prompt.

For example, just type:

`cd \mongodb\bin`

and then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use this powershell that dowloads mongodb and installs it as windows service...
https://gist.github.com/serdarb/5102848

Comment: Any idea how to do this as part of a windows installer project?  I'm trying to do something similar but as part of a windows installer project.  We've got a Silverlight project in VS2010 and it has a web setup project with a custom action but now we need to include mongodb as part of the installation.  Trial and error and googling hasn't yielded any results yet. Any ideas?

Comment: visual studio (2010) installer project

Comment: i don't have much experience in setup projects, but maybe you can run ps1 file in a step? http://0ptikghost.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/executing-powershell-scripts-silently.html